# revertedWith not matched error message

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat, chai

I am expecting a revert from an Imported Ownable.sol contract since the executing address is not the owner of the function but the test fails without matching the error message thrown from the Ownable.sol contract.

**HardHad Config:**

```
const path = require('path');
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers');
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle5");
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox')
require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env')});
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url : (process.env.INFURA_KOVAN_URL + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY),
      }
    }
  },
  solidity: "0.8.9",
};
```

**Smart Contract:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Custodian is Ownable {

    function helloWorld() public pure returns(string memory){
        return "Hello World";
    }

    function goodByeWorld() public view onlyOwner returns(string memory){
        return "Goodbye World";
    }
}
```

**JS Test:**

```
it('goodbye world from owner', async ()=> {
    await expect(this.custodian.goodByeWorld({ from: other })).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")
  });
```

**Error:**

> Contract: Custodian
> goodbye world from owner:
> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Ownable: caller is not the owner'

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a very similar error as this, and after a lot of searching, this discussion proved helpful to me, [specifically this comment here](https://github.com/TrueFiEng/Waffle/issues/95#issuecomment-1036791938)

The important bit is that apparently BigNumbers matchers use `expect(await)`, all other matchers are shown using `await expect()`.

Also worth considering [this comment](https://github.com/TrueFiEng/Waffle/issues/95#issuecomment-1028185162) about if the reversion is require or not.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `await` to inside the `expect`, like so.

```
it('goodbye world from owner', async ()=> {
    expect(await this.custodian.goodByeWorld({ from: other })).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")
  });
```

Comment: I tried but its giving me the same issue.

Comment: Although @Kenzo Agada is not completely wrong, this worked for me too once. I still haven't figured out why. But moving the `await` in and out works sometimes differently. In one of my cases removing it completely worked for me too. I don't have an explanation for it tho.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out why. But moving the `await` in and out of the `expect` function works sometimes differently.

Other answers included moving the `await` inside `expect`, which works sometimes. In one of my cases, removing it completely worked too.

It's worth trying this out too:

```js
it('goodbye world from owner', async ()=> {
    expect(this.custodian.goodByeWorld({ from: other })).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner")
});
```

***NOTE: I don't have an explanation for it, tho. If you do, please let us know.***